# Advertising: Every page refresh counts as 3 ad impressions

Tags: plugins, php

I have tried multiple plug-ins for ads and for each page refresh they all count it as 3 impressions.

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Currently using the Ad Engine plugin, and already tried Simple Ads Manager.
Using an Image.

**Example Code:**

```
                    <!doctype html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding an manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Use the .htaccess and remove these lines to avoid edge case issues.
       More info: h5bp.com/b/378 -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <!--Wordpress Template-->
  <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />  

  <?php wp_head(); ?>

  <meta name="description" content="Saint Petersburg SociaBulls">
  <meta name="author" content="Austin Piazza">

  <!-- Mobile viewport optimized: j.mp/bplateviewport -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory: mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/sociabulls/js/jcar/skins/tango/skin.css" />

  <!-- CSS: implied media=all -->
  <!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />  
  <!-- end CSS-->

  <!-- More ideas for your <head> here: h5bp.com/d/head-Tips -->

  <!-- All JavaScript at the bottom, except for Modernizr / Respond.
       Modernizr enables HTML5 elements & feature detects; Respond is a polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries
       For optimal performance, use a custom Modernizr build: www.modernizr.com/download/ -->
  <script src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/sociabulls/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>


  <!-- end scripts-->

  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        // Configuration goes here
    });
});
</script>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>

  <div class="wide" id="container">
    <header id="sticky" class="wide">
        <div class="center">
        <a href="#"><h1 id="logo" class="notext">St. Pete Sociabulls</h1></a>
        <ul id="nav">
            <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

<div id="page">
<div id="top"><div id="city"></div></div>
<div id="main" role="main" class="wide">
    <div id="full">
        <div class="center">
            <div id="moveup">

                <div id="main-event">
                     <h2><?php the_title('');?></h2>
                     <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
                     <div class="whole-post">

                         <div class="post-date">
                            <?php the_date( 'M d' ); ?>
                         </div>
                         <div class="entry">
                             <div class="entrytext">
                                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                   <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                </div>

                <aside>

                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')  
        || !dynamic_sidebar( 'rightsidebar' ) ) : ?> 
<?php endif; ?> 

<div id="ad-box">
                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')  
        || !dynamic_sidebar( 'Ads' ) ) : ?> 
<?php endif; ?> 
</div>

                </aside>

             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div> 


<footer class="wide">
         <div id="seawall">
            <div class="center">
                <div id="sponsors">
                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')  
        || !dynamic_sidebar( 'extra' ) ) : ?>
 <p>This is the deafult sidebar, add some widgets to change it.</p>  
<?php endif; ?> 

                </div>
                <div id="social-page">
                    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/swingstampabay" data-width="350" data-height="170" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </footer>
  </div> <!--! end of #container -->


  <!-- JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading -->

  <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/sociabulls/js/jcar/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>

  <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
  <script defer src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=270668269621466";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=265187160174054";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


  <!-- Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
  <script>
    window._gaq = [['_setAccount','UAXXXXXXXX1'],['_trackPageview'],['_trackPageLoadTime']];
    Modernizr.load({
      load: ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
    });
  </script>


  <!-- Prompt IE 6 users to install Chrome Frame. Remove this if you want to support IE 6.
       chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started -->
  <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.attachEvent('onload',function(){CFInstall.check({mode:'overlay'})})</script>
  <![endif]-->

  <?php wp_footer(); ?>  

</body>
</html>
```

**Update: Added all my code together**

Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like you're loading the Facebook JS SDK twice at the bottom there, just pointing that out! :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it's because I have a like button and like box, is there anyway to just run it once for both? They have different 'js.src' 's

Comment: Oh they have different App ID's, hmm I'd have to look it up but is another question on it's own, probably suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: Where are your ads placed? Specifically, are they anywhere but `dynamic_sidebar( 'Ads' )`?

Comment: Nope. I've also tried them as a shortcode and same issue, interesting update is: for different people it does a different number..Tested remotely with friends

Comment: Just commented out all of my widget areas on functions.php and it now works..not sure what is wrong with that code, I do need those though: https://gist.github.com/eb86ef617df64bb9ae3a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEVER NAME THINGS ANYTHING CLOSE TO NORMAL!!!!

I can't believe this entire problem was from naming my widget area 'ads'...